# OOP - Creational Pattern (Factory Method) Am I on the right path?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm learning design patterns and at this stage, I'm playing around with creational patterns, Factory Method to be precise.

The idea is to have a Factory Method to create either documents or links(symlinks) in a "virtual" filesystem.

Would someone be willing to take a look at the code and advice me and guide me to the right path ?

FileFactory.java

```
  public final class FileFactory {

public FileFactory(){}
public static IFileFactory createSoftLink(){
    return new SymbolicLinkFactory();
}
public static IFileFactory createDocument(){
    return new DocumentFileFactory();
}
```

Interface IFileFactory.java

```
public interface IFileFactory {
FileSystemElement createFile (String name, String mimeType, String currentDirectory, String user) throws IOException;}
```

DocumentFileFactory.java

```
public class DocumentFileFactory implements IFileFactory {

protected DocumentFileFactory() {}

@Override
public mFile createFile (String name, String mimeType, String currentDirectory, String user) throws IOException {
    String fName = name;
    if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("docx")) {
        fName += ".docx";
    }else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("pptx")) {
        fName += ".pptx";
    }else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")) {
        fName += ".xlsx";
    }else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("docm")) {
        fName += ".docm";
    }else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("pptm")) {
        fName += ".pptm";
    }else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("xlxm")) {
        fName += ".xlxm";
    }else {
        fName += "."+mimeType;
    }

    mFile file = new mFile();
    file.rename(fName);
    file.create(fName, currentDirectory, user);
    Path filePath = Paths.get(currentDirectory+System.getProperty("file.separator")+fName);
    file.setPath(filePath);
    return file;
}
```

SymbolicLinkFactory.java

```
public class SymbolicLinkFactory implements IFileFactory {
private FileSystemElement fsElement;

protected SymbolicLinkFactory() {}

@Override
public FileSystemElement createFile(String name, String mimeType, String currentDirectory, String user) throws IOException {
    SoftLink sl = new SoftLink(name, fsElement, fsElement.getPath(), Paths.get(currentDirectory));
    return sl;
}

public void setFileSystemElement(FileSystemElement fsElement) {
    this.fsElement = fsElement;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic in your `mFile createFile(String, String, String, String)`. Is there any reason NOT to do `fName = name + "." + mimeType;` ?

Comment: you may be right, I haven't given much importance to those details as I'm more interested on the pattern

Comment: @pelican_george You may get a better response to this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it looks fine to me. It would be better if you had some logic that showd why you would use the factory pattern, for example something that checks if the document you want to create already exists, and returns a softlink creator if it does.

As mentioned by Josh, the implementation of createFile is a bit confusing, and diverts attention from your problem/goal.

As the code stands, there is no need for the FileFactory class. All it does is to centralize/shortcut to your implementations of the IFileFactory  interface.

There are two other common use cases for factory class that might be relevant to your situation:

1. Dependency injection: Hide which implementation is actually used
   inside the FileFactory class, allow to switch implementation at
   startup/runtime
2. Factory/class families: Here you are only creating
   one instance. Imagine instead that you had two kinds of items - file
   item and folder. In that case it's important that a "file item" you
   create is of the same kind as your "folder", for exampl eso a file
   system file goes in a file system folder, and a Wiki page goes in a
   Wiki URL.